# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException using AES

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

Despite I found lot's of posts talking about the same issue I couldn't fix my issue.

I am using a c# server and a java client (in the future will be android). The curious stuff is that I am sending/receiving many json strings longer and more complex and just in the shortest and easiest fails.

This is the code for the client:

```
private static byte[] asegurarCapacidad(byte[] inicial, int tamano){

    if(inicial.length<tamano){

        return Arrays.copyOf(inicial, tamano);          
    }

    return inicial;
}    

   private static String leer(Socket s){

    byte[] buffer=new byte[4092];
    byte[] bufferFinal = new byte[8092];
    int leido=0;
    int posicion=0;
    String salida = null;

    try {       
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec("1212121212121212".getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES");
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        while((leido=dis.read(buffer))>0){
            bufferFinal=asegurarCapacidad(bufferFinal,posicion+leido);
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, bufferFinal, posicion, leido);  
            posicion+=leido;
        }
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,iv);
        salida=decodificar(cipher.doFinal(bufferFinal));

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("CLIENTE: ERROR AL LEER: "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return salida;
}
```

And this is the code of the server:

```
    private static byte[] codificar(string mensaje)
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mensaje);
    }

    private static void escribir(Socket s, string mensaje)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[mensaje.Length];
        buffer = codificar(mensaje);

        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.KeySize = 128;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.Key = bytKey;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.IV = iv;
        ICryptoTransform AESEncrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor();
        buffer = AESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        s.Send(buffer);
    }
```

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Not an expert, but you're using PKCS7 padding to encrypt, and decrypting with PKCS5Padding. My guess would also be that the way you're reading the bytes in Java is not correct: you assign bufferFinal to a large byte array, and then immediately reassign it with the result of asegurarCapacidad(), which is not shown. Why don't you send every byte read to a ByteArrayOutputStream, or directly to the Cipher?

Comment: @JBNizet PKCS#7 and PKCS#5 are essentially the same, just different names (except that PKCS#5 is only defined for 64-bit blocks, so it's a bit of a misnomer in Java).

Comment: @JB Nizet I already updated the post with the method asegurarCapacidad(). Anyway, I dunno if it will make the difference since for other several cases it works fine. For sure I am doing something wrong. But what I wonder how is it possible that many other JSON strings are well encrypted/decrypted and the most simple one is not using the code is already displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a buffer of 8092 bytes (`bufferFinal`). Suppose the input stream contains only 1000 bytes. Your code reads these 1000 bytes and calls

```
asegurarCapacidad(bufferFinal, posicion + leido);
```

where `posicion` is 0 and `leido` is 1000.

The method `asegurarCapacidad()` does the following:

```
if (inicial.length < tamano) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(inicial, tamano);          
}

return inicial;
```

where `inicial.length` is 8092 and `tamano` is 1000. So it returns the buffer unmodified.

So you end up with a buffer of 8092 bytes containing the 1000 bytes read from the input stream, and 7092 bytes set to 0. And that's what you're passing to the Cipher, instead of only passing the 1000 first bytes.

It works when you have a larger text as input, because the `asegurarCapacidad()` ends up returning a buffer larger than 8092 bytes containing only the encrypted bytes. But your code is inefficient (it reallocates a new array every time), and could be much simpler:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8092];
try {       
    InputStream in = s.getInputStream();

    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec("1212121212121212".getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    while ((leido = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        cipher.update(buffer, 0, leido);
    }

    salida = decodificar(cipher.doFinal());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Right now the exception disappeared. However, I only get the last 3 characters of every json string I receive.